# Как распарсить xml с помощью sql 2008r

Tags: sql, xml

Основная моя проблема заключается в том чтобы получить значения атрибутов узлов разных уровней.

```
@xml =    
<root>
  <params>
    <parameter id = '1' systemType= '3'>
      <results>
        <result type = '1' name = 'test'>
        </result>
      </results>
    </parameter>
    <parameter id = '2'>
      ...
    </parameter>
  </params>     
</root>
```

Мне нужно получить атрибут id у "parameter", type и name у "result".
Получилось только вывести значения атрибутов у "result".

```
select distinct T.value('(@type)[1]', 'varchar(50)') as 'type',
                T.value('(@name)[1]', 'varchar(50)') as 'name'
  from @xml.nodes('/root/params/parameter[@systemType=3]/results/result') as X(T)
```

Подскажите возможно вывести в этом запросе еще и id "parameter"?

Comment: С нижнего уровня? Прийти туда через `..` т.е. `select distinct  T.value('(../../@id)[1]', 'int') as 'id' ...`

Comment: @nick_n_a, спасибо друг за помощь помогло, оформишь как ответ отмечу)